# Removing the part of string in c# (Multiple occurence)

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am reading a HTML file using StreamReader.
I want to remove a part of string which starts with `@*` and ends with `*@`.
There can be multiple occurrences, and I want to remove them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for *akton* regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"@\*(?:[^*]+|\*[^@])*\*@");
```

if we use `"[@][*].*[*][@]"` then next will not work properly

```
"@* That was 2 *@  THIS WILL BE DELETED TOO!  @* 2. *@"
```

As bonus `(?: )` is used for deleting internal back points.

Comment: The `Multiline` option is not doing anything useful.  All it does is change the meaning of the anchors (`^` and `$`), and you aren't using those. Also, `@`has no special meaning in regexes, so you don't need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression like:

```
string input; // string containing data to be replaced
Regex regex = new Regex("[@][*].*?[*][@]", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string replaced = regex.Replace(input, string.Empty);
```

This finds all strings starting with `@*` and ending with `*@` and replaces them with an empty string, effectively removing them.

Note that this requires the entire file to be loaded as a string. A better solution might be to create a simple state machine that reads a stream and copies it into another stream until the string `@*` is found then stop copying to the other string until `*@` is found.

Comment: Doesn't that have issues with any asterisks floating around inside the substring to be removed, e.g. `end; @* That was 2 * 2. *@`?

Comment: the above code works for single line only. I have instance where @* can appear in 1st line and *@ on nth line. I want to remove the intermediate a line as well.

Comment: @DiveshSalian Answer updated. I added the RegexOptions.Multiline argument to the constructor.

Comment: Update your regex and Salian should check it as answered

Comment: @Artu Thanks for another pickup. I changed to use the lazy rather than greedy version of `*`, which should have the same effect.

Comment: The expression is greedy, which probably isn't what the OP intended.  Especially with `Multiline`.  A bit of lookahead perhaps?

Comment: Hi Akton, thanks for all your response I tried with multiline but it is not working

Comment: @DiveshSalian Did you try it with the lazy version? When you say it isn't working, what is happenning?

Comment: the string is not getting replaced. Am new to regex so dont have any exposure on it

Comment: @DiveshSalian I should have pointed out that the string `input` is not modified. Rather the new string is returned. Answer is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all matches of `@\*.*?\*@` with the empty string.

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"@\*.*?\*@", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```